# Safari fail to click only on the first test of the group TestNG

Tags: selenium, safari, testng

When I run several tests using TestNG on Safari, the first test always fails because of the click operation.

It doesn't matter what test it is as long as it has a click in it, even if I run the same exact test couple of times (using @Test(groups = {"test"}, invocationCount = 4)) only the first one can't perform a click and the others pass with no issues.

When I say click is not performed I mean the outcome of the click is not happening (for example opening a new tab or clicking on a button to change something), there is no error so the code executes the click function and move on although the click did nothing.

What could cause that difference of behavior between the first test and the tests that come after?

Here is the code of the click function:

```
public void clickOnWebCoords(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, Point pointToClick) {
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(element, pointToClick.x, pointToClick.y).perform();
    actions.click().perform();
}
```

Safari version: 14.0.2, Selenium version: 3.141.59

Comment: What's the error you encounter? Does the click just not perform? Can we see the full code you're executing? My guess is your page isn't fully loaded and you could use a wait.

Comment: There is no error, the click is just not performed. I make sure the page is loaded and the element to click on is loaded and visible.

Comment: Can you share the code?